# Iterating over single string of elements

Tags: lists, strings, literate-programming

I currently want to implement a LaTeX program, which iterates over the output of a (in my case) `perltex` command. The output is a single string with iterables separated by commas. A full working example (plus maybe some unnecessary packages):

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\usepackage{perltex}


\perlnewcommand{\foo}{
return "a,b";
}

\newcounter{counter}
\begin{document}
\foreach \counter in \foo{
Element: \counter
}
\end{document}
```

The document has to be compiled using a bash command such as `perltex --nosafe --latex=pdflatex deleteme.tex`.  Despite this seeming to be a fairly straightforward and simple problem, I can't find any solutions which include a string with quotation marks.

Is  there any way to convert such strings into readable lists or otherwise iterate over it?

The `\foreach` used in my code is from the **todonotes** package, but **tkiz** gives the same results. Please note I could not reproduce this problem with a regular `\newcommand`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please add a minimal example of code from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`?

Comment: I edited my question accordingly

Comment: LaTeX knows nothing about Perl; the expansion of `\foo` (to TeX's eyes) is `\plmac@write@perl {USE^^MIVCHAIMDBMNCDMCMXQHA^^M\foo}`, which is a single item, so you get a single cycle.

Comment: See the `listofitems` package for processing separated lists.

Answer (score 1):

The actual issue didn't lie in the combination of `\foreach` with a string, but rather in PerlTex returns not being interpreted correctly. Once I realized the problem, I created a workaround by not returning the actual string, but rather a `\renewcommand`. I added a functioning example for posterity:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{perltex}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\perlnewcommand{\foo}{
$output = 'a,b';
return '\renewcommand{\perltext}{a,b}';}




\newcounter{counter}

\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\perltext}{}
\foo
\foreach \counter in \perltext{
Element: \counter
}


\end{document}
```

Thank you to @Andrew and @egreg for getting me there.

Comment: Glad you found a solution!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\perloutput}{return "a,b";}

\newcounter{counter}
\newcommand\ProcessOutput[1]{%
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\refstepcounter{counter}\textbf{Element \thecounter}: ##1.\newline}%
  \expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter{#1}%
}
\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}

  \ProcessOutput\perloutput

\end{document}
```

This gives the output:

[image]

Some words of explanation. The [etoolbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package provides several commands for dealing with comma separated lists. One of the easiest is `\docsvlist` which will apply the current macro `\do`  to each element of the command separated list.

Comment: While your code solves the problem for regular strings, my `\perlnewcommand` output is still regarded as a single element. It seems the problem might rather lay in LaTex-Perl incompatibilities. Regardless thank you for the excellent answer.

Comment: @NN314 No your problem lies in your not explaining clearly what you want:) I interpreted your (initial, now edited) question as needing to process a command separated list, so this is what I did. I think that you needed to describe more clearly what you are trying to do because I, at least, am unable to work it out from the question.

Comment: You are of course correct. I didn't realize what the actual problem was before I tested your answer for myself. I found a rather ugly, but functional workaround for the issue, which I will post below